# Querying Salesforce REST API without getting records

Tags: api, rest, pagination, salesforce

I want to query Salesforce REST API to get metadata (`totalSize`, `done` and `nextRecordsUrl`) but without results array (`records`).

My goal is to do requests like this one: `GET https://my-company.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/query/01g670000EPHl2iAQD-1500` and only get its metadata (to be in accordance with my company pagination standards).

How can I do that?

Comment: Why? What are you actually trying to accomplish - get a record count?

Comment: I want to expose this API through my company's API Manager. Our API Manager uses an offset - limit pagination system, so I have to "map" requests to Salesforce API.